# Can't open Veracrypt files on host system (win10) from guest (ubuntu) in Vitualbox

Tags: windows, ubuntu, virtualbox, veracrypt

I get this error every time I try to mount a file:

```
Input/output error:
/dev/mapper/veracrypt5

The drive is damaged (there is a physical defect on it) or a cable is
 damaged, or the memory is malfunctioning.

Please note that this is a problem with your hardware, not with VeraCrypt.
Therefore, please do NOT report this as a bug/problem in VeraCrypt and please 
do NOT ask for help with this in the VeraCrypt Forums. Please contact your 
computer vendor's technical support team for assistance. Thank you.


Note: If the error occurs repeatedly at the same place, it is very likely 
caused by a bad disk block, which should be possible to correct using third-
party software (note that, in many cases, the 'chkdsk /r' command cannot 
correct it because it works only at the filesystem level; in some cases, the 
'chkdsk' tool cannot even detect it).

VeraCrypt::File::ReadAt:306
```

The "readat" location is the same every time. Setup is Win10 host with veracrypt files that are too big to put on the guest. Ubuntu guest in virtual box using shared drives to the host automounted.

I've tried:

- Creating a new volume from inside the Ubuntu guest (the existing one was made in Windows) on the idea that maybe the file system of the container was incompatible, but that gave the same error.
- Creating a new volume on the host that was much smaller.
- Changing permissions on the shared drives in Ubuntu to 777 (it ignored me and only made it 770, but w/e
- Added myself to the vboxsf group (or whatever) that owns the drive.

So far nothing has worked or helped in any way. Is there another way to share files between them that's more robust? I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Is the VeraCrypt volume you're trying to open a single file? Can you copy it (anywhere)? Are there any errors/messages showing up in `dmesg` or the syslog (`/var/log/syslog`) when VeraCrypt complains, like disk or I/O errors?

Comment: It's a single file. What do you mean copy it? You mean move it around on the host system FROM the guest? That works fine... i seem to have ok permissions.

Comment: dmesg says:

print_req_error: I/O error, dev loop10, sector 20352
[  276.140669] Buffer I/O error on dev loop10, logical block 2544, async page read

Comment: Var/log/syslog prints this on the attempt:
<pre>
Mar  2 09:17:08 jcom kernel: [  446.611241] print_req_error: I/O error, dev loop10, sector 20216

Mar  2 09:17:08 jcom kernel: [  446.611243] Buffer I/O error on dev dm-0, logical block 2495, async page read

Mar  2 09:17:08 jcom gvfsd-metadata[2107]: g_udev_device_has_property: assertion 'G_UDEV_IS_DEVICE (device)' failed

Mar  2 09:17:08 jcom snapd[2099]: udevmon.go:190: udev monitor observed remove event for unknown device "/sys/devices/virtual/block/dm-0"</pre>

Comment: Those look like errors... and yes, try copying the file to a local / guest drive, maybe there's just something weird that won't let you read the file, or maybe the physical disk it's on is having problems. (Moving a file around the same partition doesn't usually really move anything, just changes the filesystem entry of what directory it's in)

Comment: Yup. Copying the small file over works. So we know it's something about how the sharing works between the host and guest. Now what?

Comment: That sounds about right, since copying the file worked maybe it's only the way the loop file tries to access it that's going wrong, maybe it's not even supported... At any rate a workaround is to copy the file into the host, I suppose I'll post that as an "answer" since it seems to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rebuilt my VMs with Vmware instead of Virtualbox and it seems to work.